# Installing nodejs to my VirtualBox apache server cause a block entering the IP from different PCs on LAN

Tags: php, node.js, apache, codeigniter, virtualbox

Until now I have used apache2 on an Ubuntu server and usually code with PHP (CodeIgniter).

I have installed nodejs on Thursday and I notice today I cant connect to the website (using the virtualbox IP address) from other computers on the LAN.

I am suspecting it has to do something with the ports/proxies of nodejs. (enabled proxy and proxy_html)

what can be the problem?

Comment: this has nothing to do with nodejs, unless you are running some proxy server using nodejs. try running this command **netstat -tupln | grep 80**. asuming you are running you website on port 80.post the output here

Comment: `tcp6  0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN 1632/apache2`

Comment: this means your apache server is running fine on port 80.was it accessible before using **VM**?

Comment: It *is* because of node.js. 
I answered the answer bellow. 
Tnx for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/166068/port-seems-to-be-open-but-connection-refused

> I had this problem recently with a nodejs HTTPS server, and the
>   solution to it was not to use "localhost", "127.0.0.1" or even the
>   domain name. It was to use "0.0.0.0"
>
> I believe this acts as a wildcard, now allowing for public resolution
>   via the domain name and it also works with "localhost"
>
> Edit: Here's a link to a serverfault page on the 0.0.0.0 topic:
>   https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1

It is because of the Node.js. 
I changed `127.0.0.1` in the `/etc/hosts` file to `0.0.0.0` and now it's working.